# How do I select the greatest view value?

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to get the map that has the greatest view value?

```
String api =
    'http:///';

await Dio().get(api).then((value) {
  //  print(value);
  if (value.toString() != 'null') {
    for (var items in json.decode(value.data)) {
      print(items);

      Map<String, dynamic> greatestView = items.fold(
          {},
          (previous, current) => previous['view'] == null
              ? current
              : previous['view']! >= current['view']!
                  ? previous
                  : current);

      print(greatestView);
```

Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'fold'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
Tried calling: fold(_LinkedHashMap len:0, Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic))

Comment: Please click [edit] and include the relevant details as text, not broken image links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a list of maps, and you want to get the map that has the greatest view value? I propose something like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> greatestView = data.fold({}, 
  (previous, current) => previous['view'] == null
    ? current
    : previous['view']! >= current['view']! 
      ? previous
      : current
  );
```

It looks like `view` is a string, here is the code in that case:

```
Map<String, dynamic> greatestView = data.fold({}, 
  (previous, current) => previous['view'] == null
    ? current
    : int.parse(previous['view']!) >= int.parse(current['view']!) 
      ? previous
      : current
  );
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DHHq.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `view` was a string, I recommend View shouldn't be a String, but if there is a good reason for it to be, I've updated my answer

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it right or not ?, I've updated

Comment: no, get rid of the for loop, like this: `final value = await Dio().get(api);` then: `if (value != null) {}` and then: `Map<String, dynamic> greatestView = value.fold({}, [...]`

Comment: String api =
        '$http//;

    final value = await Dio().get(api);

    if (value != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> greatestView = value.data.fold(
          {},
          (previous, current) => int.parse(previous['view']) == null
              ? current
              : int.parse(previous['view']!) >= int.parse(current['view']!)
                  ? previous
                  : current);
      print(greatestView);
    }

Comment: Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'fold'.
Receiver: "[{\"view\":\"1\",\"id_products\":\"10\"}]"
Tried calling: fold(_LinkedHashMap len:0, Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic))

Comment: wait, your data is a String? that seems like a weird Dio error with your api, but for now, do me a favor and do this: `final response = await Dio().get(api);` and then `if (response != null && response.data != null) {...}` `final value = jsonDecode(response.data)` and see if that works, also you have to add `import 'dart:convert'` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuHiR.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtcIF.jpg

I'll take the id_products with the most views.

Comment: Does it still not work? What is the problem?

Comment: I thank you very much for helping me, if not for you I would be bad. I spent a lot of time doing it. And I'm not fluent in English, I use google translate.